# Lazy Loading of <img> or background-image

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have a list of users in my app, a jQuery-UI [`accordion`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). It looks good, but the problem is, that each accordion contains the user's avatar.

It used to be an  before, but now I just set the background-image. By now, a lot of users are on the site, and since this page is now 1 MB of data, I feel like I should reduce.

Is there an easy to way to make sure the image is only ever loaded when viewed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lazy load plugin for jquery,
here is the demo http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html
are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work. If it were me, I would just load them all after the DOM finishes loading.

```
$(this).on('click', function(event) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'http://...'; // Whatever the source is. I would store it in as data attribute in 'this'.
    this.appendChild(img);
})
```